# How can I expand both a variable name and a wildcard in a file name?

Tags: bash, globbing

I have a bash script where `$DIR` is a directory name that may contain spaces.

This:

```
rm "$DIR/*.MOV"
```

gives the error "No such file or directory". There is no file literally named "*.MOV"; I want the `*` to expand into multiple arguments - one per matching filename.

Eg:

```
rm some\ folder/foo.MOV some\ folder/bar.MOV
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting prevents globbing. Try this with GNU bash:

```
rm "$DIR"/*.MOV
```

Comment: I usually use `{}` when I want to append or modify something about my variable, like this: `${DIR}/*.MOV`. I don't know which of these is better, but using `{}` works for my use cases every time.

Comment: jena, it won't work if $DIR has spaces in it—try it with `x="a  b"; echo ${x}` (notice the two spaces in the variable value), which "echo" expands to two arguments before adding a single space between them.

Comment: @MihaiDanila - it works just fine.  use quotes AND braces (sorry code in comments looks terrible) :  
`$  x="a       b";echo ${x}
a b
$ x="a       b";echo "${x}"
a       b
`

Answer (score -1):

A workaround:

```
for FILE in `ls "$DIR" | grep .MOV`; do
  rm "$DIR/$FILE"
done
```

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - Isn't it just better to not use newlines in your filenames? Who would do that anyway? I'm not a sysadmin, I'm working on datafiles produced by me and my colleagues and although one of them is crazy (ADHD among other things), putting newlines into filenames is just crazy and I would have such filename fixed. In the link they even suggest putting timestamps into filename just to avoid *not putting* newlines in them - wtf?

Comment: @jena Isn't just better to not spill oil on your floor? Who would do that anyway? Maybe a *rogue* who wants to *exploit* the fact you're careless. Besides: accidents happen, poorly written archivers unpack files with strange names etc. If you want to parse `ls`, it's your choice, you have been warned. People who'd like to use this answer in their projects, where they deal with *filenames of unknown origin*, should be warned as well before they `rm` too much.

Comment: I partially agree, as I said, I'm not a sysadmin but a scientist, so I generally work on secured clusters on files produced by me & colleagues. If I use standard tools and work with sensible people, I can parse `ls` just fine, am I right?